# After deployment Web job, execution of blob trigger stopped working

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-deployment, webjob

I have deployed my web job on production environment and suddenly blob trigger stops working(Looking into App Insight I know that blob trigger is not called).

If I debug the same code from the local machine then it triggers blob trigger.But stopped working in the production environment.

Always On is enabled.

Also, I have these containers are present
azure-jobs-host-archive, 
azure-jobs-host-output, 
azure-webjobs-dashboard, 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,

Installed packages:-

Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs installed version is 2.0.0, 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host installed version is 2.0.0

Comment: How far below? ;-)

Comment: I didn't get you Peter.

Comment: You say "Below is web job setting" I do not see any. But anyway, this is really hard for us to tell. How does the code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, we couldn't directly find out why the blob trigger doesn't work. I suggest you could follow below way to troubleshoot by yourself.

> If I debug the same code from the local machine then it triggers blob trigger.But stopped working in the production environment.

Since you found your webjob could work well in local, I guess maybe there are something wrong with the connection string config in your web app.

I suggest you could try to follow below way to change the production environment appsetting to set the storage connection string in it.

1.Open the portal and edit the appsetting as below.

[image]

2.Create another web app and publish the web job to it and run.

If these two ways all doesn't help you solve the error, I suggest you could post the log/error message and  the details codes about the web job.

More details about how to find the log/error message, you could follow below way.

[image]

Comment: Yes, connection strings are different.After correcting it, web jobs works good.

Comment: If you feel my answer is useful /helpful.Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.